# display large image and text side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with alignment on case 3:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZKYva

Relevant html code:

```
<div>

  <img class="img-valign" src="http://www.placehold.it/550x1050" alt="" />
  <span class="text2" style="white-space: pre;">some text3 some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3 some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3some text3</span>

</div>
```

Relevant css code:

```
.img-valign {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
```

I want the text to be at the side of the large image like in case 1 and case 2 and not have it overflow. 
How can i do this?

Update (important detail): I need white-space: pre; on the text to preserve formatting.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.flex {
    display:flex
}
```

Then give the div that surrounds your third image/text pair `class='flex'`. You may need to adjust some other attributes but this should get you on your way.  For further information, do a search on Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the big image and add float:left  to it.

HTML:

```
<img class="img-valign1" src="http://www.placehold.it/550x1050" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
    .img-valign1 {
        float: left;
    }
```

then you can arrange your text.

Comment: What if I need the text to have  white-space: pre; to preserve formatting? If I add that, it messes up the alignment with the image.